# Two column enumerated list

Tags: examples

I want to make an example with a two column enumerated list, but with enough space for the kids to write their answers on the in the example; attached is a photo of what I am looking for.[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). This question could be useful https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125087/equal-spacing-with-enumerate-and-multicol?rq=1

Comment: See also the packages [tasks](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks) and [hlist](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hlist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned @jfbu's comment into an answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\settasks{after-item-skip=4em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=3ex,
          counter-format=(tsk[a]),
          column-sep=2em
          }

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task First left column
\task First right column
\task Second left column
\task Second right column
\task Third left column
\task Third right column
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: How can I add more spaces in between rows?  This kids need to write.

Comment: @JoshuaJones: Add `\settasks{after-item-skip=2cm,after-skip=2cm}` in your preamble to set the vertical space between items to 2cm (or any other length of your choice) for all `tasks` environment in your document.

Comment: Last question: How do I put vertical space between the two columns?

Comment: I suppose you mean *horizontal* space between the columns?

Comment: @AboAmmar: To reproduce the O.P.'s labelling, you should add `\settasks{counter-format =(tsk[a])`.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, I have included these.

Answer (score 0):

Making some editions to the code from [Equal spacing with enumerate and multicol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125087/equal-spacing-with-enumerate-and-multicol?rq=1), we have

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\subproblemhang}
\newcommand{\subproblem}[3][.45\linewidth]{%
  \settowidth{\subproblemhang}{(#2)~}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{#1}
    \hangindent=\subproblemhang\hangafter=1%
    (#2)~#3
  \end{minipage}%
}
\newcommand{\dg}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

%Problem 1
\item[] \textbf{Exercise \#2}. Consider the trigonometric equation $\sin(\theta)=-\dfrac13$ over the interval $0\dg\leq\theta\leq360\dg$. \\

\subproblem{a}{determine the reference angle for this problem by evaluating $\sin^{-1}(1/3)$. Round to nearest \textit{tenth} of a degree.}\hfill
\subproblem{b}{In what quadrants is the sine function negative?}

\vfill

\subproblem{c}{Draw the rotation diagrams for the two angles that terminate in the quadrants specified in (b) that have the reference angle from (a).}\hfill
\subproblem{d}{Using your answers from (a), (b) and (c), solve the equation $\sin(\theta)=-\dfrac13$ over the interval $0\dg\leq\theta\leq360\dg$. State your answer to the nearest \textit{tenth} of a degree.}

\vfill

%Problem 2
\item Second problem goes here.

\vfill

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```