# How to continue enumeration in tasks environment after page break and new text box

Tags: math-mode

I'm a math teacher and trying to recreate many Algebra math worksheets (problem sets) that were originally created with the monstrously inefficient mathtype app. the Voldermort of equation editors IMHO.

I seek your help in solving what seems like a simple problem. My format is 2 column with horizontal enumeration. However, after I inserted a manual page break command and a text box to identify the start of a new section of the worksheet, LaTeX re-started the numbering at 1 instead of continuing the enumeration which ended at #10 on page 1 and should be #11 on page 2.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

%\printanswers % uncomment to print solutions.
% MACROS
%Not sure all of these packages are necessary...but the 'taks package is certainly necessary
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption} % allows captions in minipage envir (issue w/solutions envir)
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{framed} %box para
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
%\displaystyle for all $$ math environments use \lim\limits for other environments

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

%\unframedsolutions % uncomment to remove boxes from solutions
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % removes paragraph indentation

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\header{Exponents Quiz #1: Product and &Quotient Properties}{}{03/12 - 03/13/19 (Day 6)} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% -------------------------- DOCUMENT STARTS HERE -------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}


\vspace{4mm}

\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{7.5 in}{
\textbf {Obj. Q.8.b:} I can use the PRODUCT PROPERTY to simplify exponential expressions (10 pts. tot.) \\
\newline
Simplify by expanding with repeated multiplication.YOU WILL NOT RECEIVE CREDIT IF YOU SKIP THIS STEP!!! Your answer should only contain positive exponents.}}}


%Use the 'tasks' tool to double column itemize and enumerate
%Credit to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402222/two-column-enumerated-list
%the first item sets the spacing
\settasks{after-item-skip=8em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=3ex,
          %change '1' to 'a' if you want letters instead of numbers
          counter-format=(tsk[1]),
          column-sep=2em
          }

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $3x^4\cdot 4x^3$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-2x \cdot 2x^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $4a^2 \cdot 4a^0$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4x^0 \cdot 4x^2 \cdot 2x^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $4m^4n^3 \cdot 4m^2n^3$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4m^3n^4 \cdot 2m$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $4nm^0 \cdot 4m^4n^2$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4a^0b^2 \cdot ba^3$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $a^4b^2c^3 \cdot 2a^2b^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4zx^4y^4 \cdot -3x^3y^0z^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\end{tasks}

\pagebreak

\makebox[\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}

\vspace{4mm}

\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{7.5 in}{
\textbf {Obj. Q.8.b:} I can use the QUOTIENT PROPERTY to simplify exponential expressions (10 pts. tot.) \\
\newline
Simplify by expanding with repeated multiplication.YOU WILL NOT RECEIVE CREDIT IF YOU SKIP THIS STEP!!! Your answer should only contain positive exponents.}}}
\vspace{0.5mm}

%Use the 'tasks' tool to double column itemize and enumerate
%Credit to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402222/two-column-enumerated-list
%the first item sets the spacing

\settasks{after-item-skip=8em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=3ex,
          %change '1' to 'a' if you want letters instead of numbers
          counter-format=(tsk[1]),
          column-sep=2em
          }

%[counter-format = tsk[R], label-format=\normalfont,  after-  skip=1\medskipamount](3)

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $3x^4\cdot 4x^3$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-2x \cdot 2x^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $4a^2 \cdot 4a^0$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4x^0 \cdot 4x^2 \cdot 2x^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $4m^4n^3 \cdot 4m^2n^3$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4m^3n^4 \cdot 2m$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $4nm^0 \cdot 4m^4n^2$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4a^0b^2 \cdot ba^3$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $a^4b^2c^3 \cdot 2a^2b^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4zx^4y^4 \cdot -3x^3y^0z^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I think you'll increase your chances of getting help if you simplify your example a bit (i.e. get rid of all the stuff that is not required to reproduce your problem)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `resume` key.

I also made some adjustments, avoiding repetitive tasks that are error prone. The page top can and should be defined as a macro, `\settasks` should be issued just once.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

%\printanswers % uncomment to print solutions.
% MACROS
%Not sure all of these packages are necessary...but the 'taks package is certainly necessary
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption} % allows captions in minipage envir (issue w/solutions envir)
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{framed} %box para
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
%\displaystyle for all $$ math environments use \lim\limits for other environments

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

%\unframedsolutions % uncomment to remove boxes from solutions
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % removes paragraph indentation

\pagestyle{head}
\header{Exponents Quiz \#1: Product and \& Quotient Properties}
       {}
       {03/12 - 03/13/19 (Day 6)} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
  \makebox[\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}\par
  \vspace{4mm}
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf {Obj. Q.8.b:} I can use the QUOTIENT PROPERTY to simplify 
    exponential expressions (10 pts. tot.)\par
    \bigskip
    Simplify by expanding with repeated multiplication.
    YOU WILL NOT RECEIVE CREDIT IF YOU SKIP THIS STEP!!! 
    Your answer should only contain positive exponents.
  }}}\par
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=8em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=2em,
          item-indent=3em,
          %change '1' to 'a' if you want letters instead of numbers
          counter-format=(tsk[1]),
          column-sep=2em
          }



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% -------------------------- DOCUMENT STARTS HERE -------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\pagetop

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $3x^4\cdot 4x^3$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-2x \cdot 2x^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $4a^2 \cdot 4a^0$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4x^0 \cdot 4x^2 \cdot 2x^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $4m^4n^3 \cdot 4m^2n^3$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4m^3n^4 \cdot 2m$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $4nm^0 \cdot 4m^4n^2$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4a^0b^2 \cdot ba^3$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $a^4b^2c^3 \cdot 2a^2b^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4zx^4y^4 \cdot -3x^3y^0z^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\end{tasks}

\clearpage

\pagetop

\begin{tasks}[resume](2)
\task $3x^4\cdot 4x^3$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-2x \cdot 2x^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $4a^2 \cdot 4a^0$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4x^0 \cdot 4x^2 \cdot 2x^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $4m^4n^3 \cdot 4m^2n^3$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4m^3n^4 \cdot 2m$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $4nm^0 \cdot 4m^4n^2$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4a^0b^2 \cdot ba^3$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $a^4b^2c^3 \cdot 2a^2b^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\task $-4zx^4y^4 \cdot -3x^3y^0z^4$
\begin{solution}
solution
\end{solution}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also fixed `#` and `&` to `\#` and `\&`. Using `\\ \newline` is not a good way to get a vertical skip: I used `\bigskip` instead.

Comment: Dear egreg: I can't thank you enough for your amazingly helpful response and expert fix of my code. I also deeply appreciate that you went the extra mile to fix other problems, e.g. # and & changed to \# and \&. I originally entered the teaching profession because I have an intense desire to learn and share knowledge with other. You have been a great ally to me. Thanks so much.