# Please teach me how to raise the height of the exponent

Tags: formatting

Could someone please teach me how to raise the height of an exponent attached to a fraction?

I tried many of the fixes in various forums without success.

Also, please explain the difference between using \struct^ vs ^.

Many thanks!

Here's my code...

```
\begin{document}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}


\vspace{4mm}

\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{7.5 in}{
\textbf {Directions:} Solve the equations below. 
\newline
\newline \textbf {REQUIRED 1st step: Rewrite the original equation and place parentheses ( ) around each variable.} \\
\newline
YOU WILL NOT RECEIVE CREDIT IF YOU SKIP THIS STEP!!!}}}


%Use the 'tasks' tool to double column itemize and enumerate
%Credit to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402222/two-column-enumerated-list
%the first item sets the spacing
\settasks{after-item-skip=8em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=3ex,
          %change '1' to 'a' if you want letters instead of numbers
          counter-format=(tsk[1]),
          column-sep=2em
          }

\begin{tasks}(2)
\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\task $\frac{2}{3} \div \biggr(-\frac{2}{7}\biggr)\strut^{2}$
```

Comment: Please complete the code such that it starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, and can be compiled.

Comment: How or where are the `tasks` environment and the `\task` and `\settasks` macro defined?

Comment: \mathstrut is bigger than \strut, but as Mico pointed out, removing the strut is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked,

> Could someone please teach me how to raise the height of an exponent attached to a fraction?

I've simplified your code snippet to the bare minimum and made it compilable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\biggl(-\frac{2}{7}\biggr)\strut^{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

(Aside: I also replaced `\biggr(` with `\biggl(`.) `l` and `r` stand for "left" and "right", respectively.)

I have no idea why the `\strut` instruction is in there. For sure, it completely messes up the typesetting. If you omit it, the exponent (`2`) will be placed at the correct height.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\biggl(-\frac{2}{7}\biggr)\strut^{2} \quad  % awful
\biggl(-\frac{2}{7}\biggr)^{2}       \quad  % better
\biggl(-\frac{2}{7}\biggr)^{\!2} % even better: place exponent closer to closing parenthesis
\]
\end{document}
```

You also asked, "Also, please explain the difference between using `\struct^` vs `^`." (Aside: I will assume you meant `\strut`, not `struct`.) Basically, I have no idea what the purpose of writing `\strut^{2}` might be; where did you pick up this bad habit? Unlearn it as quickly as you can, please.

Comment: Mico: Please accept my long-delayed thanks for your very helpful answer. As a latex newbie, I have to rely on whatever answers I can find on the www.  Can't thank you enough for helping me out!